# sapui5 how to provide placeholder for sap.m.Select Tag

Tags: sapui5

How can we add placeholder for [sap.m.Select](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.Select). Using `sap.m.ComboBox` we can get placeholder. But i dont want to use that.

Im trying to do some work around by getting placeholder through odata response. Im able to get that. But the problem is it will be available in the list of dropdown values.

If i set the placeholder value to disable, then placeholder will not be visible. But it will be available in dropdown in disabled mode.

Can someone help me to get placeholder for `sap.m.Select`

Thank you in advance

Comment: By placeholder do you mean setting the default value once the collection for the select has been returned? A Select has to have an item displayed and therefor placeholder does not apply.

Comment: How about setting the placeholder value as initial and after selection made? for e.g `this.getView().byId('selectId').setSelectedKey('--placeholder--')`   or from core as  `sap.ui.getCore().byId('selectId').setSelectedKey('--placeholder--')`

Comment: @Codenewbie, Here im getting response from Odata. if we are doing setSelectedKey('placeholder'). Then the problem is like it will be available in dropdown with the list of dropdown values. It will not suite my requirement.

Comment: @Bernard, Before returning the collection i want to show the placeholder. Even after receiving response from OData, im not doing 'forceSelection' as 'true'. It is 'false'. We need to select the item by clicking dropdown. Before that there must be one placeholder like "Please select value"

Comment: Then it is better to put Validation if user selects `palceholder` and for showing an error(a red border) kind , you can  use `setValueState("Error")`

Comment: Given this is not an intended use for Select (which does not allow input, only selection) why would you not use the ComboBox?

Comment: @Bernard, Actually My project is complete Customized project with 10 Screensand lot of CSS changes. If i go with ComboBox my CSS is getting collpased and look and feel is getting changed. To avoid that i want to use only Select. Otherwise i need to do few more customizations..